# Pasar htmlAttributes a EditorFor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Buen día!

Estoy trabajando en plantillas para **EditorFor** para los distintos tipos de datos, específicamente `int` y `double` con fin de generarlos en tipo texto, con un `oninput` que me valide que no ingresen información incorrecta.

Comencé con la plantilla de **Int32** y funcionó todo correctamente, excepto que no encuentro la vuelta de como hacerle llegar atributos extra

Para que se interprete mejor;

**La plantilla (~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Int32.cshtml)**

```
@model int?
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, null, new { @type = "text", @oninput = "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')" })
```

Al utilizarlo en una **Vista**, obtengo el resultado deseado

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CampoInt)
```

El problema, se da cuando quiero pasarle algún atributo extra a EditorFor;

**Por ejemplo**

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CampoInt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } } )
```

El problema aquí es que ambos casos renderizan lo mismo.

```
<input oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')" type="text">
```

y yo lo que pretendo, sería que en el segundo caso, se renderizara de lo siguiente

```
<input oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')" type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Asumo, que de alguna manera debo recibir un parámetro dentro de la plantilla **Int32.cshtml**, pero llevo un buen tiempo buscando y no encuentro solución, alguien se ha topado con un problema similar?

Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Hola. Aquí dejo un enlace con una posible solución. Espero te ayude.
http://omarventuri.blogspot.pe/2011/07/how-to-pass-parameters-to-aspnet-mvc3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solución

Gracias a una respuesta en el foro de [stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061954/custom-editorfor-template-and-htmlattributes), la solución fue la siguiente:

```
@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(attributes);
    htmlAttributes.Add("oninput", "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')";
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, htmlAttributes)
```

Muchas gracias a todos por gastarse el tiempo de leer la pregunta! Saludos!

Comment: +1 por utilizar [AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper.anonymousobjecttohtmlattributes?view=aspnetcore-2.0) que es algo esta "oculto" es muy util para realizar este parseo

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una solución.
En tu template Int32.cshtml:

```
@model int?

@{
    var actualData = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "type", "text"},
        { "oninput", "this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')"},
    };

    var viewData = ViewData["htmlAttributes"];
    if (viewData != null) {
        var type = viewData.GetType();
        var props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props) {
            actualData.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(viewData));
        }
    }
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, null, actualData)
```

Y como lo usarías:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Cantidad)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Cantidad, new {htmlAttributes = new {@readonly = "readonly"}})
```

Espero te ayude